# StreamProvider.value returns same value multiple times : Flutter

Tags: flutter

StreamProvider.value is building the widget multiple times with same value.

```
StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
      value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, child:MyWidget);

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Consumer<FirebaseUser>(
      builder: (context, _user, _) {
if(_user!=null){
 print(_user.uid); 
return Container(Text(_user.uid));
 } 
else return Container();

 }
}
```

Output:

flutter: RlKE7123WKSLKP9AgLCFgY40Wx1

flutter: RlKE7123WKSLKP9AgLCFgY40Wx1

Tried using Selector instead of consumer but end results were same but not sure i used it correctly. Can you help me to sort this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)?

```dart
StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Error!");
    } if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data.uid);
    } else {
      return Text("waiting for data ...");
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: I am using the firebase uid in my entire app by Provider.of<Firebase>,  that why using streamprovider.

Comment: I dont understand, what you are asking ... Bar and Baz in that context are obviously example classes, but i dont understand the relevance here ... And you can use Provider and StreamBuilder together. Apart from that, i don't see a Provider.of in your code sample, it is just not clear what you are trying to do. When you are trying to rebuild something, each time the stream emits an event, StreamBuilder is a way to do this.

Comment: Used Selector as below but results were same.     Selector<FirebaseUser, Tuple2<String, String>>(
        selector: (_, data) => Tuple2(data.uid, data.uid),
        builder: (_, data, __) {
          print(data.item1);
  }
).

Comment: Using the value of Uid through out my entire App with provider class.  I am loading streamprovider at very top of app as runApp(StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
      value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, child: MyApp()));

Comment: okay, and why don't you just use the provider package like in the examples (https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value): `return Text(context.watch<FirebaseUser>().uid);`

Comment: and to further elaborate, this still can emit the same uid over time, because the firebase user object can change, while the uid does not, or the stream emits the same event twice ... check distinct for that: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/distinct.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215690/discussion-between-scrimau-and-flutter-raj).